# Windows Phone app can't access a web service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, windows-phone-8, http-status-code-404

I'm  writing an application for Windows Phone 8.1. I have hosted a WCF service on IIS Express on my local machine and configured it to be accessible from the WP8 device that I'm using for testing (done all the endpoint config, added firewall rules etc). I have no problem accessing my service from the smartphone's web browser, so I guess it is not a server config issue. But when I do the same request from within my app, I get a 404 response.

Here's the code that sends the request.

```
client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.144.1.104:50102/EntityService.svc/");
var builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append("player/register?id=");
builder.Append(deviceId.ToString());
builder.Append("&nickname=");
builder.Append(nickname);

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, builder.ToString());
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
var dataString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultDTO>(dataString);
```

I want to point this out once again, when I copy the formed request link in the phone's web browser, it works fine. I have no idea why it gives me 404 in the application. Does anyone know what's the reason for this?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I have checked, and IIS Express did not log any requests that are sent from the app.
P.P.S. In the appmanifest, Internet (Client/Server) capability is checked, so it shouldn't be an application permission issue.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668183.aspx

try this way

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For some reason they don't allow to add service references to Windows Phone 8.1 apps, that's why I have to write the service client layer by myself.